# Classic folder link in modern view yields error "Cannot read property 'formType' of null."

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, error, microsoft-teams, bug

From a Microsoft Teams channel I click the button "Open in SharePoint". This in turn opens a new browser window with a deep link to the channel folder in the SharePoint document library. The folders and documents show up just fine - but the Details Pane in the modern list view yields the following error:

> Cannot read property 'formType' of null.

[image]

The deep folder link from MS Teams looks like this:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/site/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fteams%2Fsite%2FShared%20Documents%2FGovernance&FolderCTID=0x012000CC8990B7BFBD724A85EF6F5E6D922972
```

That looks like a link to a folder in a SharePoint classic view! If I instead navigate within the SharePoint modern view, the link has this format:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/site/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FolderCTID=0x012000CC8990B7BFBD724A85EF6F5E6D922972&viewid=0ba872ad%2D6a2f%2D4d04%2D87ca%2D0ade68976127&id=%2Fteams%2Fsite%2FShared%20Documents%2FGovernance
```

That works fine - no error in the Details Pane. The error only shows when the following conditions are true:

- The document library is browsed in Modern view (Classic works)
- The SharePoint language is Danish or any other language than English
- The folder is opened with deep-link formatted as a classic link shown above.

Can anyone confirm if this is a known bug?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: I tried the same and it is working fine for me. URL is also in the same format as your first link and it is opening in Modern View only. (Language is set to English).

Comment: Thanks for testing - it also works for me when the SharePoint site language is set to English. But it fails when setting it to my native language Danish.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was caused by user's experiments with content types of list.  The CT of  particular documents were set to "Unknown", after changing to Document everithing  got fine.